# Verbatim string alternatives in JAVA

Tags: java, string

Knowing that Java doest have verbatim strings (@) like in C#,is there way to keep the format of a string when using it in the code?I have a sql code i have to use inside the code,but for readability i have to keep it in a certain format,i can do that in c# using @,but how can i achieve that in Java?

For example:

```
String SQL=@"INSERT INTO VERSION_INFO
        ( TABLE_NAME ,
          VERSION_ID ,
          DATE,
          EXP
        )
VALUES  ( '' , -- TABLE_NAME - varchar(50)
          0 , -- VERSION_ID - int
          0 , -- DATE- int
          ''  -- EXP- varchar(100)
        )";
```

I have to use this as is,without much modification...

edited for stupidness...

Answer (score 5):

If you use Eclipse, you can use the below `@formatter` tags:

```
// @formatter:off

String string = "Your beautifully"
    + " formatted string";

// @formatter:on
```

Anything between these tags will be immune to a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (`Source > Format`).

Answer (score 2):

What can I say, other than... sorry.

```
String SQL = "INSERT INTO VERSION_INFO (\n"
           + "    TABLE_NAME,\n"
           + "    VERSION_ID,\n"
           + "    DATE,\n"
           + "    EXP\n"
           + ")\n"
           + "VALUES (\n"
           + "    '' , -- TABLE_NAME - varchar(50)\n"
           + "    0,   -- VERSION_ID - int\n"
           + "    0,   -- DATE- int\n"
           + "    ''   -- EXP- varchar(100)\n"
           + ")";
```

Comment: whops i forgot the quotation marks i guess :P But still,its not the case :)

Comment: What I'm saying that, in standard Java, it doesn't get much better than what I've written in this answer.

Comment: Would not the java code also need the newline (\n) to generate the same string as the C# verbatim string?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö, yes of course. I didn't think it was important in this case. Adding it...

Comment: To avoid the trouble of manually having to type in `\n`, you could also enable the options "Wrap automatically" and "Escape text when pasting into a string literal" under `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Typing`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Java doesn't  give Verbatins .

You can use `String` `format` method to achieve this.

**Example:**

```
String str= "Hello %s, isn't %s cool?";
String formatted = String.format(str,"Ivan", "Scala");
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Same way you can first write your query and then you can format your query String.

**e.g.**

```
String SQL="INSERT INTO VERSION_INFO
    ( TABLE_NAME ,
      VERSION_ID ,
      DATE,
      EXP
    )
VALUES  ('%s','%s',%s,'%s')";

String.format(SQL,--set as order---);
```

I think it can help you.